# how to learn EXTJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I know jquery and javascript but never worked on other frameworks like EXTJS.
can somebody tell me the best way to quickly learn EXTJS? and also what is the process to configure EXTJS? Is it in the same way like we configure jquery (by just adding a standard js file)? or something else.

Thanks

Comment: should this be on [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend Jorge Ramon's excellent [ExtJS 3.0 Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198708) - it's what I used to learning by actually doing stuff. The projects start out pretty easy, and goes through everything to do with configuring ExtJS.

Once you've got the basics, the Sencha tutorials and FAQs are ok, but I reckon that for reference, the best resource they've got by far is their [API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/).

Finally, Jozef Sakalos (aka Saki) has made some awesome examples on his blog and on his [ExtJS Examples](http://extjs.eu/) site.

Good luck learning ExtJS!

Answer (score 10):

Quite a few tutorials on this website:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorials

Or have a look at the answer to this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001112/ext-js-tutorial-or-videos

Try Garcia's book 'Ext JS in action'
http://www.manning.com/garcia/

Answer (score 0):

I always read files from here [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/)
and use it as my reference for my tasks/projects